# Python selenium поиск элемента по имени класса и тексту через xpath

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, python-2.7

Есть cтраница на которой находится 4 одинаковых элемента, но с разным текстом
Запрос

`browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='MyClassName']")`

возвращает мне сразу все 4 элемента. Элементы отличаются лишь текстом. Я знаю часть этого текста, так как другая часть содержит время и ID. Я могу их получить через сравнение с текстом, но это выглядит ужасно, долго и сложно.

`[x for x in browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@class='MyClassName']") if my_text in x.text][0].click()`

Можно ли как-то получить элемент по имени класса и через contains text?
Я пробовал

```
browser.find_elements_by_xpath( "//*[@class='MyClassName' and [contains(text(),'{}')]]".format(my_text))
```

Но selenium ругается `SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string "//*[@class='MyClassName' and [contains(text(),'Custom')]]" is not a valid XPath expression.` Вопрос: как составить правильный xpath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
browser.find_elements_by_xpath( "//*[@class='MyClassName' and text()[contains(.,'{}')]]".format(my_text))
```

Answer (score 0):

Я бы предложил цикл по элементам.
Но если совсем не хочется, то может помочь SelectorGadget.
Это плагин для Chrome. Помогает обратиться к конкретному элементу как через CSS-селектор, так и через xpath.

Comment: Написано же через Selenium

Comment: Селектор можно через инструменты разработчика генерировать. Но по тексту они не создаются автоматически.